# Folder share not working between specific machines

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

I have three servers. I created a shared folder in server1 and made it available to all machines in LAN. The issue now I am facing is that only one of the other two able to browse the shared folder.

When windows diagnostic ran from the server(from where no connection is happening) it says the remote machine is not responding.

But the other machine is able to access the shared folder.

Can anyone suggest any solution.

Comment: have you verified the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you should verify on all hosts:

- Are all hosts members of the same domain or workgroup? Check with `echo %USERDOMAIN%`.
- Are all hosts in the same subnet? Check with `ipconfig /all`.
- Can all hosts resolve all hostnames forward and reverse? Check with `nslookup`.
- Is the Windows Firewall disabled or does it have the appropriate allow rules when it's enabled? You should allow ports 137/udp, 138/udp, 139/tcp and 445/tcp. For simplicity try disabling the Windows Firewall entirely on all hosts.
- Can the NetBIOS names be resolved? Check with `nbtstat -r`.

Comment: Yes they are all the member of the same domian Group.
Hosts are in the same subnet.(server1-->server2 and vise versa connection is not working, server3 can connect to any of them)
Windows Firewall is enabled.-ping is working between those Servers.

I will update you if anything above helps